# error after upgrade vb to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb6-migration

i upgrade my project to vb.net by using visual basic. i get a error when run the crystal report.

```
    Call ReportConnection(CInspAuditList, "A")
    CInspAuditList.ReportFileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\A.rpt"
    Call SubReportConnection(CInspAuditList, "A")
    CInspAuditList.set_ParameterFields(0, temp1)
    CInspAuditList.set_ParameterFields(1, temp2)
    CInspAuditList.set_ParameterFields(2, temp3)
    CInspAuditList.set_ParameterFields(3, temp4)
    CInspAuditList.Action = 1
```

my connection is

```
Public Function ReportConnection(ByRef CrystalReport1 As Object, ByRef dsnname As String) As Boolean

    Try
        CrystalReport1.Connect = "dsn=" & dsnname & ";UID=" & gstrID & ";PWD=" & gstrPassword & ";DSQ="
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End
    End Try
End Function
Public Function SubReportConnection(ByRef CrystalReport1 As Object, ByRef dsnname As String) As Object
    Dim NReport As Short
    With CrystalReport1
        NReport = .GetNSubreports
        Do While NReport > 0
            .SubreportToChange = .GetNthSubreportName(NReport - 1)
            .Connect = "dsn=" & dsnname & ";UID=" & gstrID & ";PWD=" & gstrPassword & ";DSQ="
            .SubreportToChange = ""
            NReport = NReport - 1
        Loop
    End With
End Function
```

i get error `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A501B` at `CInspAuditList.Action = 1`

may i know how to fix the error???

Comment: What is `CInspAuditList` - can you post the code where this is declared - if you have this working in VB6 it may be useful to show this code so we can compare the two.